# Subsequence of an array

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

This function calculates the largest possibly number x such that all number 1,...x-1 are in an array e.g. {1,3,2,5} -> 4. Function does not work for arrays with zero as It always then returns 1. Why is that?

```
int array(int* t, int r)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < r; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < r-1; y++)
        {
            if (t[y] > t[y+1])
            {
                int temp = t[y+1];
                t[y+1] = t[y];
                t[y] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i != r; i++)
    {
        if (t[i] != (i + 1))
        {
            return i+1;
        }
    }
    return r+1;
}
```

Comment: I don't fully understand your requirement. What is the relationship between `Z` and `x`?

Comment: Typo. My mistake.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that in your example x=4? But the largest numer in the array is 5, so x+1, not x-1?

Comment: Are you just looking for the maximum value in the array? Why do you switch values inside the array then?

Comment: @KarstenKoop No, what he means in this example is that numbers 1, 2 and 3 are in the array so the answer is 4. You don't have 4 in the array otherwise answer would have been 6.

Comment: @KarstenKoop:  1 and 2 are elements of the array, so result could be 3 (except it is not the largest such value).  4 is *not* an element of the array, so result cannot be 5.

Comment: Ah, you are looking for a consecutive sequence of numbers in the array. Now I understand. So in the first phase of the alogrithm you are doing a selection sort, right?

Comment: @vforbiedronka:  The first pair of `for` loops would be much better being replaced with `std::sort(t, t+r);`.  This will be faster, and it will be right!

Comment: @KarstenKoop: I think that's a bubble sort.

Comment: @vforbiedronka: What value do you *want* an empty array to give?  It's not obvious to me what the right answer is.  Actually, strike that:  What answer do you want back if there is *no* such number in general.  For example, if the array contains `{2,3}`?

Comment: It is a bubble sort i guess than i want to find largest possibly number X such that all number from 1 to X-1 are present in an array.

Comment: Why do you think the result you get is wrong? If the result is supposed to say that your array contains `1- (X- 1)`, then doesn't it make sense that if your array contains all zeros then the result should be `1`? i.e. the range `1 - 0` thus implying that the search did not yield meaningful results?

Comment: Than i want to have zero as there is No largest X.

Comment: Because i checked It and when i have e.g. {0,1,2,3,5} It gives me 1 not 4 as It should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When checking the sequence of sorted numbers, you check that `t[i] == i+1`, so if the `i`th element is at position i. This only works if your sequence starts with 1. Instead you should check that the `i+1`th element is the `i`th element +1, so

```
if (t[i]+1 != t[i+1]) {
  return t[i] + 1;
}
```

Comment: It works with zero but when zero is not in an array it returns numberiwant-1

Comment: You are right, I just changed the `if` clause but the returned value was also off: you don't want to return the index of the element, but the element itself, incremented by one, so not `i+1`, but `t[i]+1`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's break up your code

```
for(int x=0;x<r;x++){
   for(int y=0; y<r-1;y++){
       if(t[y]>t[y+1]){
          int temp=t[y+1];
          t[y+1]=t[y];
          t[y]=temp;
      }
   } }
```

This is a sorting algorithm (Bubble Sort, kind of). So after these loops, we can assume that your array is sorted.

Now if you'll look in the next for loop, the loop checks the presence of (i+1)th number for each i. That means, in the first iteration (i=0), it'll check for 1 (i+1) in the 0th position. If it does not find that, it'll return that value or else keep searching. If everything goes fine, it'll return r+1 (size of array + 1).

```
for (int i = 0; i != r; i++) {
    if (t[i] != (i + 1)) {
        return i + 1;
    }
}
```

Now, if there is a 0 in the array (with all positives), it will always occupy the first position (0th index). Hence it returns 1, as it was expecting 1 in the 0th index.

If you understood this, I don't think, it would be tough for you to accommodate for 0 as well.